# jQuery Knob Release function additional parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-knob

I'm using the jQuery Knob plugin https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob

Now, I've got the following jQuery Knob Initialization

```
loop
   <input type="text" value="<?php echo $score; ?>" class="circle-rating" data-entryid="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
endloop



$(function() {
    $(".circle-rating").knob({
            'min':0,
            'max':10,
            'step':1,
            'width':40,
            'height':40,
            'fgColor':"#F59B00",
            'inputColor':"#F59B00",
            'displayPrevious': true,
            'release' : function (v) { 

                var entry_id = $(this).attr('data-entryid');

                jQuery.post("/path/to/file/update_library_score.php", {v : v, entry_id : entry_id}, function(data) {
                    console.log(entry_id);
                    jQuery('#notification-general').html(entry_id);

                });
            }

    });
});
```

The main issue is that I have multiple knobs on the page. These knobs are actually in a loop with wordpress posts.

Anyway, each knob is attached to an `ID` and this `ID` changes as you go through the loop.

Now to be able to update the score I need two things the knob's `value` which I get from the `release` function and I also need the `post_id` which I can only get within the loop. So how can I get the `post_id` variable to this function?

Usually I can simply add a `button` or a link with a `onclick="my_function(<?php echo $post_id; ?>)` however, I can't do it with this. What's the best way of grabbing the $id that corresponds with this knob and passing it to the release function as a parameter?

Comment: you could use custom attributes via `data-*` to he `.circle-rating` elements and access it via $(this).attr('data-*') in your release function. where * may be any string u want

Comment: @Nouphal.M I've updated my question with what you said (I think) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what does entry_id output?. check in console or alert the value and

Comment: @Nouphal.M fixed a syntax error and tried `console.log(entry_id);` as you can see in the updated question code and console returns `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in release function

```
alert(this.$.attr('data-entryid'));
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WhCLk/1/)

Comment: Yup, seems like `this.$.attr('data-entryid')` works instead of `$(this).attr('data-entryid')`