# Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined class jQuery

Tags: jquery

HTML

```
<input type="number" id="progress-update-1234" class="progress-update" data-entryid="1234" data-updateItem="progress" value="3" min="1" max="15" />
```

jQuery

```
$( ".progress-update" ).change(function() {

    var entry_id = this.$.attr('data-entryid');
    var item_entry = this.$.attr('data-updateItem');
    var new_progress = $("#progress-update-" + entry_id).val();

    alert( "This is progress update" + entry_id + " and type " + item_entry + " and new progres " + new_progress );
});
```

I'm not exactly sure why this is returning an error: `Cannot call method 'attr' of undefined` in the console. I am using `this` inside the `change` function that is attached to the right class. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Where did you see `this.$` used?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856236/jquery-knob-release-function-additional-parameter

Comment: Take a look at this question, which I also asked and some how `this.&` is working over `$(this)`

Comment: That's a weird property that the jQuery Knob plugin author decided to set.

Comment: ahh all right, thanks for clearing it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
var entry_id = $(this).attr('data-entryid');
```

`attr` is a jQuery function that's why it can use only with jQuery objects. `this` not a jQuery object but `$(this)` is.

Answer (score 1):

your code should look like this

```
var entry_id = $(this).attr('data-entryid');
```

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap the element with jQuery

```
var entry_id = $(this).attr('data-entryid');
var item_entry = $(this).attr('data-updateItem');
```